# How make an sub-array of permutations with duplicates from array of n elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

I try to use an array to iterate all posibilities of combine n element from an array:

```
array = ["9","0","1","2"];
```

For example the function `combine(array,iter)` with `iter=2` shuld return:

```
["90","09","91","19","92","29","01","10","02","20","12","21","99","00","11","22"]
```

Parameters are define:

```
array: original array with all elements to combine.
iter: number of elements to result in combine with duplicates.
```

I try using yield, but without results, the quantity of elements are correct but, the value is wrong:

```
//Thank you to le_m for the code in ES6!
function* express(tokens, size) {
  if (size < 1) yield [];
  else
    for (var item of tokens) {
      for (var combination of express(tokens, size - 1)) {
        yield combination.concat(item);
      }
    }
}

array = ["9","0","1","2"];
for (iter of express(array,2)) {
    console.log(iter)
}

Console Output:
[ '9', '9' ]
[ '0', '9' ]
[ '1', '9' ]
[ '2', '9' ]
[ '9', '0' ]
[ '0', '0' ]
[ '1', '0' ]
[ '2', '0' ]
[ '9', '1' ]
[ '0', '1' ]
[ '1', '1' ]
[ '2', '1' ]
[ '9', '2' ]
[ '0', '2' ]
[ '1', '2' ]
[ '2', '2' ]
```

Comment: Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried at Question?  What are the benchmarks of the approaches that you have tried? What do you mean by "efficient"? "efficient" compared to?

Comment: @guest271314 Now it's a simple way

Comment: Ok. I edit the question.

Comment: i find clear ideas to attack this problem, my solution is very nasty.

Comment: @randiel _"Now it's a simple way"_ The same standard applies. What have you tried to resolve your own inquiry? "simple" is a relative term. "simple" compared to?

Comment: @randiel _"my solution is very nasty"_ You have not included your current solution as `javascript` or algorithm at the text of the Question itself.

Comment: @guest271314  without anonymous user pls. Who are you?

Comment: @randiel _"without anonymous user pls. Who are you?"_ Not sure what you mean? And who this user is or is not is irrelevant to the Question.

Comment: Is very easy criticizing with guest user.

Comment: @randiel It is unfitting to address the topic where you have not put forth effort to solve your own inquiry; whether the topic be permutations or any other subject. You need to share what you have tried to resolve your own inquiry.

Comment: That is the problem.. ok is not the first time, but i don't understand when i help to answer questions, i don't matter that.

Comment: _"Someone knows simple way?"_ is lackluster effort, at best; the peak of the effort being asking the Question itself. At least you hardcoded the result. Though can view no effort at creating an algorithm or using code to produce the expected result at Question. Not certain what you are expecting as responses? At least put forth effort into trying to code and, or constructing a cohesive algorithm that is, the steps necessary to produce expected result in descriptive form. Then try to reduce the code to the minimal parts; that is the rudiments of trying to form "simple" from potentially complex.

Comment: Shouldn't "01" and "10" be part of the above result, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to generate all possible combinations of a given length. There are n^length combinations in total. To avoid the possibly huge memory requirement, I recommend using [a generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```js
// Return all combinations of 'length' elements from array:
function* combine(array, length) {
  if (length < 1) yield [];
  else for (let element of array) {
    for (let combination of combine(array, length - 1)) {
      yield combination.concat(element);
    }
  }
}

// Example:
console.log(...combine(["9", "0", "1", "2"], 2));
```

Comment: This is the way but what happends when i want k as size of elements, not only 2 elements k in range [2-10]

Comment: in my function express i don't know iterate array values with each value of my iterator: exp = i + express(tokens,arr,size);

Comment: @randiel Just change `length` to any value k, e.g. `combine([1, 2, 3], 3)`

Comment: is only for ES6?

Comment: @randiel yes, generators have been introduced with ES6

Comment: for previous version there are generators, but send me this message: express {[[GeneratorStatus]]: "suspended"}__proto__: Generator[[GeneratorStatus]]: "suspended"[[GeneratorFunction]]: function* express(tokens,size)[[GeneratorReceiver]]: Window[[GeneratorLocation]]: VM345:45[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]

Comment: My last result is: `[ '9', '9' ]
[ '0', '0' ]
[ '1', '1' ]
[ '2', '2' ]
[ '9', '9' ]
[ '0', '0' ]
[ '1', '1' ]
[ '2', '2' ]
[ '9', '9' ]
[ '0', '0' ]
[ '1', '1' ]
[ '2', '2' ]
[ '9', '9' ]
[ '0', '0' ]
[ '1', '1' ]
[ '2', '2' ]`

Comment: @randiel Do you have any further questions about this answer? It is working as required. The code you included in your question is flawed, just replace it with this answer and it will work.

Comment: thanks @le_m i change a little for standard javascript! previews to ES6!